# JSON Parser Error when selecting the PayPal payment method on Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, paypal-sandbox, spree, spree-paypal-express

I have installed the better_spree_paypal_express extension successfully, but each time i select the PayPal payment option, I get the error below.

```
757: unexpected token at '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><SOAP-ENV:Header><Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security><RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType"><Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType"><Username xsi:type="xs:string">xxx</Username><Password xsi:type="xs:string">xxx</Password><Signature xsi:type="xs:string">xxx</Signature><Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject></Credentials></RequesterCredentials></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0"><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Timeout processing request</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
```

I have searched online for possible solution without success.

<del>I'm also wondering why it is a SOAP response?</del>

Please, has anyone had this issue or know a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the credentials you are using for paypal are incorrect. Please check your settings for paypal in your backend. Since you are using the `better_spree_paypal_express`, you must make sure you are specifying the correct `Solution` (Mark, Sole etc). Apart from that, the login/password/signature/server need to be correctly configured as well.

Please note: If this is the development environment, you need to use the `sandbox` server settings.

Comment: Hi @IshaanS I have tried with Solutions Mark and Sole, specified sandbox because its in development. ! still get the same issue. My other login credentials seem ok because when i change the to the wrong thing I get a different error pertaining to wrong credentials.